# Can i use PiecewiseExpand to expand If statements with function arguments?

Tags: symbolic, piecewise

Usually `PiecewiseExpand[]` is able to convert `If[]` statements to `Piecewise` functions, e.g.

```
If[a, b, c] // PiecewiseExpand
(* Piecewise[{{b, a}}, c] *)
```

If however i want to do the same with an `If` that contains function arguments this doesn't work:

```
If[a, b &, c &][d] // PiecewiseExpand
(* If[a, b &, c &][d] *)
```

Ideally i would like to get

```
(* Piecewise[{{b[d], a}}, c[d]] *)
```

Is there an easy way to do this with `PiecewiseExpand` that i'm overlooking? (maybe with an option like `Method->?`). Or is there maybe another elegant solution for this?

Comment: `(If[a, b[#], c[#]] &@d// PiecewiseExpand)`

Comment: @N.J.Evans: Thanks! This already solves my problem :) I think you should post it as an answer!

Comment: `If[a, b &, c &]` is an odd construct; the Functions have no Slots.  Is that really representative of your code?  If not what does it actually look like?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: In my actual problem the functions actually have slots, so the code looks more like `If[cond,f[#]&,g[#]&]`, but the code in my question seemed like a more minimal example. I thought they should be equivalent, no?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  It depends on one's perspective I guess.

Comment: Please see my answer for why I believe the distinction was important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is almost right, there's just a problem with the function syntax. You need to tell `b`, and `c` they'll be acting on some slot `#` then provide the argument and `&` should come after all the functions taking the argument have been specified:

`If[a,b@#,c@#]&d//PiecewiseExpand`

Comment: I'm going with this as an answer as it is the most straightforward and concise solution to my original problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
If[a, b &, c &][d] /.If[t__][s_] :> (If[t] /. Function[f_] :> f[s]) // PiecewiseExpand
```

Or package the rules into a named rule for something neater

Comment: Nice, i was thinking there must be a rule-based solution to this, but couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this fits your requirements, and I find it rather elegant:

```
pwIf[if_If @ a__] := MapAt[#@a &, if, 2 ;;] // PiecewiseExpand
```

Either of these forms work:

```
If[a, b, c][d]           // pwIf

If[a, b[#] &, c[#] &][d] // pwIf
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{b[d], a}}, c[d]]
>
> Piecewise[{{b[d], a}}, c[d]]
> ```

Also:

```
If[a, b, c][x, y, z] // pwIf
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{b[x, y, z], a}}, c[x, y, z]]
> ```

Note that your given example does not *appear* to work, but that is only because `b &[d]` is simply `b`, and `c &[d]` is simply `c`.

```
If[a, b &, c &][d] // pwIf
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{b, a}}, c]     (* this is correct output *)
> ```

---

#### Extension

If you wish to perform this expansion as part of a larger `PiecewiseExpand` operation then here is a [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) variation:

```
pwExpandAll = PiecewiseExpand[ # /. if_If @ a__ :> MapAt[#@a &, if, 2 ;;] ] &;

UnitStep[x - If[a, b[#] &, If[i, j, k]][d]] // pwExpandAll
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{1, (a && x - b[d] >= 0) || 
>     ( !a && x - Piecewise[{{j, i}}, k][d] >= 0)}}, 0]
> ```

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting so much thought into this! Great answer and even more general solution than i anticipated!

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke I am glad you found value in it.  I must say I do not understand your choice of Accept as that answer does not seem to do anything particularly useful. (Sorry N.J.Evans)  I mean why not just write `If[a, b@d, c@d] // PiecewiseExpand` if that is what you want? `b@#` and `c@#` are *not* functions and not natural elements from which to assemble an expression.  I tried to show how one could handle this kind of code in a way that is not a mere tautology.

Comment: I value your solution for the deeper insight, and you're right, it's probably more true to the way i posed the original question. But, when i asked the question, my main concern was actually to make it work for my real problem at hand as soon and easy as possible, which N.J.Evans answer did perfectly! If i ever have to make this work for more general cases, i'm glad you contributed the more general solution for this.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke I see.  Thank you for explaining. :-)